# How to created a circular progress that can handle data visualization for 3 different values using Mui CircularProgress

Tags: material-ui

I have the following code for mui v5 CircularProgress how to be able make it show 3 diffrent values at once ?

```js
export const StatusCircle: React.FC<Props> = ({ a, b, c }) => {
 
return (
<StyledBox>
<StyledCircularProgress size={50} thickness={4} variant='determinate' sx={{ color: 'red' }} value={a} />
<StyledCircularProgress size={50} thickness={4} variant='determinate' sx={{ color: 'green' }} value={b} />
<StyledCircularProgress size={50} thickness={4} variant='determinate' sx={{ color: 'yellow }} value={c} />
</StyledBox>
);
};
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a pie chart like https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/PieChartWithCustomizedLabel using `CircularProgress`?

Comment: @Hamidreza exactly

Comment: Why don't you use charts instead?

Comment: I don't want to spam my project with 1.000.000 thing I need to keep things clean and there is only one instance where I use this pie … so it is an over kill

Comment: Answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/76924994/3212379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stack all three `CircularProgress` components on top of each other. To achieve this, set the position of each to `absolute`, and give the wrapper element a position of `relative`.

```js
const StyledBox = styled(Box)({
  position: "relative"
});

const StyledCircularProgress = styled(CircularProgress)({
  position: "absolute"
});
```

By default, `CircularProgress` has a rotation applied to it which makes it start from the top. For the second and third `CircularProgress`, we want them to start where the first one ended. To do this, we need to modify the rotation for the second and third `CircularProgress` components.

This rotation property is added directly to the element's style, not its classes. So, you can override it using inline styling.

To determine where the next color should begin, calculate the percentage of progress that is colored. For example, let's say the first color covers **20%** of the progress. We need to convert this percentage to degrees to match the circular layout. If we consider **360** degrees in a full circle, **20%** corresponds to **72** degrees. However, due to the default rotation, we need to adjust this value. Subtracting **90** degrees accounts for the starting point, resulting in **-18** degrees for the second color.

```js
const firstDeg = (a / 100) * 360 - 90;
```

For the third color, we apply a similar technique, but this time we need to add the values from both the first and second colors. This combination gives us the starting point for coloring the third section of the progress.

```js
const secondDeg = (((a + b) / 100) * 360).toFixed(2) - 90;
```

We're experiencing issues with fraction to decimal calculations in JavaScript, that's why we used `toFixed(2)`.

[image: Edit mui-circular-progress-3-colors]

Comment: thanks the rotation was the issue... now I know.

Comment: btw what is the deal with style and sx, the sx dont work with transform.. and style is needed, seems to me an issue with mui ...

Comment: @Richardson Rotation property is added directly to the element's style, not its classes. So, you need to override it using inline styling.